# Problem displaying Icon in a button in windows xp(SP2) (MFC)!

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I had a problem in displaying icon in button along with the Text in MFC application.. after reading lot of arctilces I got a solution for that and it worked great.But when I tested my application in win xp(SP2)..it suprised me by not showing the icon..Check the below code which i used to display the icon along with a test in button..Please let me know if there are any fix for this issue..waiting for your replies

```
HICON addIcon = (HICON)LoadImage(AfxGetApp()->m_hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON4),
      IMAGE_ICON,0,0,LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);    

 SendMessageA(::GetDlgItem(m_hWnd,IDC_ADD),BM_SETIMAGE,IMAGE_ICON,(LPARAM)(DWORD)addIcon);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using VS2008 (you should), use CMFCButton from the Feature Pack. It has much better support for bitmapped buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that i can't get it to work (on Win2003, my primary development machine) and a brief search on the web found many complaints but no viable answers.

My only suggestion would be to do an ownerdraw button - handling the WM_DRAWITEM message is not difficult and may resolve this issue for you across the board.

see "[Native Win32 Theme aware Owner-draw Controls without MFC](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/buttons/nativewin32xpthemes.aspx)"